# Inconsistencies with RuntimeInformation OS checks when using mkbundle

Tags: c#, mono, mkbundle

I'm using `RuntimeInformation.IsOSVersion(OSPlatform.Linux)` to detect whether the operating system that the application is being run on is Linux or not.

When simply building a `.exe` using Mono (Ubuntu Xenial), and running it with `mono example.exe`, calling it returns `true`, as it should. However, when using `mkbundle` to make a native Linux executable, and calling it with `./example`, calling it returns `false`. Below is an example of the code I'm using:

```
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSVersion(OSPlatform.Linux))
{
    //do some linux specific stuff
}
else
{
    //do some windows specific stuff
}
```

Is there any way I can fix this issue, or more reliably detect the OS the program is being run on?

Comment: File a bug: http://github.com/mono/mono

Comment: Thanks, I already have @SushiHangover

Comment: if you have filed the bug, please tell us the URL of it